# file upload with angular-base64-upload no file selected text still appears even file is selected

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, base64, angular-material

This is implementation example of  [angular-base64-upload](http://embed.plnkr.co/MTzfQASN8ZVeocAq7VcM/preview) (Click see demo)

The issue is that , when I select the file , text **No file selected** with browse button still appear even file is selected !

is that issue in api ? or something missing in demo ?

Comment: It works fine for me. There are multiple examples on the demo page each with its own list. Are you sure you are looking at the right one?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am talking about Single File Selection, When I select single file , it successfully show in the below list , but text with Browse button `No file selected` still appearing after single file selection.

Comment: @AluanHaddad its must show file name with browse button

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem, and found, that this plugin clears the input  title after file was selected. The model associated with the control still works fine. Plugin author added this feature at the latest version (0.1.22), on the 26'th April, to resolve this bug: https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload/issues/66

There is another issue in the project list: 
https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload/issues/103
according to our problem. So, I hope, this problem can be solved soon.